# 'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. When trying to run code in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

when i try to run c# code in VS code it gives 'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
in the output section and i have already downloaded dot net from microsoft.

Comment: You may find your answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261688/trouble-running-c-sharp-code-in-vs-code-getting-scriptcs-error